# Changing the link color in .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using:

```
div.innerHTML = "<span style='color:#FF0000'><a href='https://www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Link Text</a></span>"
```

and would like `Link Text` to appear in Red.

Comment: And the issue you're having is...? Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

Just add the style in the a tag:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
div.innerHTML = "<a href='https://www.google.com/' target='_blank' style='color:#FF0000'>Link Text</a>"
```

```html
<div></div>
```

> Consider to use css classes instead add inline styles. Classes are more meaninful and global.

Answer (score 0):

you should definitly use classes, then you are much more flexible:

This should work:

```
div.innerHTML = "<span><a class='link' href='https://www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Link Text</a></span>"
```

And your CSS:

```
.link, .link:hover, link:active, link:visited {
    color:#FF0000
}
```